# MySQL save results of EXECUTE in a variable?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

How do I save the results of EXECUTE statement to a variable? Something like

```
SET a = (EXECUTE stmtl);
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you want to do this with a prepared statement, then you need to include the variable assignment in the original statement declaration.

If you want to use a stored routine it's easier. You can assign the return value of a stored function directly to a variable, and stored procedures support out parameters.

Examples:

Prepared Statement:

```
PREPARE square_stmt from 'select pow(?,2) into @outvar';
set @invar = 1;
execute square_stmt using @invar;
select @outvar;
+---------+
| @outvar |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
DEALLOCATE PREPARE square_stmt;
```

Stored Function:

```
delimiter $$
create function square_func(p_input int) returns int
begin
  return pow(p_input,2);
end $$
delimiter ;

set @outvar = square_func(2);
select @outvar;
+---------+
| @outvar |
+---------+
|       4 |
+---------+
```

Stored Procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure square_proc(p_input int, p_output int)
begin
  set p_output = pow(p_input,2);
end $$
delimiter ;

set @outvar = square_func(3);
call square_proc(2,@outvar);
select @outvar;
+---------+
| @outvar |
+---------+
|       9 |
+---------+
```

Comment: 'set @invar = (select ... )' in the first example will also work. I've figured it out, but thanks.

Comment: Could you share your figured out solution?