# MySQL How to get results after PREPARE and EXECUTE in Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, variables, variable-assignment, execute, procedures

My current code is :

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE sample (IN _car VARCHAR(15))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _a INTEGER;
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM train WHERE ', _car, '<=0;');
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

END\\
```

But I wanted to capture the answer of the SELECT statement to my _a variable.

I tried changing my code to

```
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO', _a,' FROM train WHERE ', _car, '<=0;');
```

But that didn't work.

Help, please?

SOLVED!

```
DELIMITER \\

CREATE PROCEDURE sample (IN _car VARCHAR(15))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _a INTEGER;
        SET @var = NULL;
        SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @var FROM train WHERE ', _car, '<=0;');
        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        SELECT @var;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END\\
```

:D

Comment: Why didn't you write simply `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM train WHERE _car <=0;` in your stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608668/mysql-save-results-of-execute-in-a-variable) you need to include the variable assignment in the original statement declaration. So you statement would be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM train WHERE ?<=0 INTO _a
```

Then you you would execute it with:

```
EXECUTE stmt1 using _car;
```

And get the result with:

```
select _a;
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: It didn't work: Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_car' at line 7