# How to set a variable to the result of a stored procedure inside a Trigger MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a little problem here, I'm making a trigger for my DB work, but I don't know how to use a stored procedure inside a trigger, I want to save the result of the procedure in a variable and then use the variable later on an IF comparator, this is my code:

---

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE TRIGGER insert_players AFTER INSERT ON players FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE A varchar(50);
set A = CALL consult_sex(player_name); //I WANT SOMETHING LIKE THIS
IF A != FEMALE THEN
INSERT INTO males (id_player, player_fullname, player_celphone)
VALUES (new.id_player, concat(new.player_name, " ", new.player_lastname), new.player_phone);
END IF; 
END;
@
```

---

Could someone help me with this doubt? Would be wonderfull, thanks.

Comment: Stored procedures do not return values, they "return" result sets; but you can use `out` parameters. Or you can use a stored function, that can return a value, instead.

Comment: A stored proc can return multiple result sets (typically 0 or 1), can modify `out` parameters, and can write directly to User variables (those with @ signs). The trick, in general, is knowing the way that the calling routine can handle those out variables or even prep to handle them. So, it other words, how you pull it off might be highly dependent on the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 4):

have your procedure take a `OUT` parameter like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE consult_sex(player_name VARCHAR(20), OUT player_sex VARCHAR(10))
```

In your procedure `SET` the value like

```
SET player_sex = <your query to get sex>
```

Call your procedure passing a parameter

```
call consult_sex(player_name, @out_value);
select @out_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a stored routine to return a value, then you need a stored **function** not a stored procedure. Using a stored function, the statement would be as follows:

```
SET A = consult_sex(player_name);
```

This is an dummy function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `consult_sex`(player_name VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(6) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

    DECLARE v_sex VARCHAR(6);

    -- Randomly generate one of two values, MALE or FEMALE
    SET v_sex = (SELECT CASE FLOOR(1 + RAND() * (3-1)) WHEN 1 THEN 'MALE' ELSE 'FEMALE' END);

    RETURN v_sex;
END
```

The trigger code you provided has some syntax errors. Given that the table and column names are correct, this would work with a stored function:

```
DELIMITER @
CREATE TRIGGER insert_players AFTER INSERT ON players FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE A VARCHAR(50);
    SET A = consult_sex(NEW.player_name); 
    IF A != 'FEMALE' THEN
        INSERT INTO males (id_player, player_fullname, player_celphone)
        VALUES (NEW.id_player, CONCAT(NEW.player_name, ' ', NEW.player_lastname), NEW.player_phone);
    END IF; 
END;
@
```

Please be sure to double-check the spelling of the `player_celphone` column.

Comment: But consult_sex is a stored proc, not a function.

Comment: If it is literally a stored procedure, then it needs to be rewritten as a stored function.