# Mysql Execute stmt output

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

This is MySQL procedure.
How can I receive the output into the variable?

this is an analyze statements in a loop.
this return many results to the code and I would like to save those results in the log table.

result example :
alonpdb.XXX analyze status  OK

```
SET @analyze_stmt = CONCAT('ANALYZE TABLE ', @v_table_name);
PREPARE stmt FROM @analyze_stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Are you looking for [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609807/5452965)

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this in mysql alone. Analyze table is a utility statement, not a select, and mysql handles these resultsets differently. You may have to use an external programming language for this.